# What causes mineral classification downgrade?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

One of my colonized planets has just had its mineral classification downgraded from "ultra-rich" to "rich":

[image: Xanthus Prime mineral classification downgraded]

What causes this? Can I fix it? Is there a way of preventing this from happening in the future?

Comment: Did your planet get to 100% `dirty`? I don't know the exact phrasing, I hope that you know what I mean.

Comment: @KhorneHoly I'm pretty sure my pollution was well below 100%. Additionally, I was under the impression pollution leads to degradation in planet class, not mineral classification, see [this wiki article on pollution](http://masteroforion.gamepedia.com/Pollution).

Comment: It was just a guess, I don't have the game yet, just watching some YouTube videos about it. Therefore I just know that pollution can change something, but not what exactly. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a mineral classification change is just one of [the random events that can occur](http://masteroforion.gamepedia.com/Random_events):

> ### Planet mineral richness increase/decrease
>
> Either through a random discovery of new mineral deposits or random depletion of existing ones the production rating of a planet can increase or decrease one grade, respectively. The player has no control over discovery or depletion of mineral deposits.

I guess there was some GNN report about this that I was not paying attention to.